# gensim(1.0.1) Doc2Vec with google pretrained vectors

Tags: gensim

For gensim(1.0.1) doc2vec, I am trying to load google pre-trained word vectors instead of using `Doc2Vec.build_vocab`

```
wordVec_google = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)    
model0 = Doc2Vec(size=300, alpha=0.05, min_alpha=0.05, window=8, min_count=5, workers=4, dm=0, hs=1)    
model0.wv = wordVec_google    
##some other code 
model0.build_vocab(sentences=allEmails, max_vocab_size = 20000)
```

but this object `model0` can not be further trained with "labeled Docs", and can't infer vectors for documents.

Anyone knows how to use doc2vec with google pretrained word vectors?
I tried this post:  http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/
but it does not work to load into `gensim.models.Word2Vec` object, perhaps it is a different gensim version.

Comment: a similar question has several answers on how to load pretrained vectors into the Doc2Vec model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470670/how-to-use-gensim-doc2vec-with-pre-trained-word-vectors?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The GoogleNews vectors are just raw vectors - not a full Word2Vec model.

Also, the gensim Doc2Vec class does not have general support for loading pretrained word-vectors. The Doc2Vec algorithm doesn't need pre-trained word-vectors – only some modes even use such vectors, and when they do, they're trained simultaneously as needed alongside the doc-vectors.

Specifically, the mode your code is using, `dm=0`, is the 'Paragraph Vectors' PV-DBOW mode, and does not use word-vectors at all. So even if there was a function to load them, they'd be loaded – then ignored during training and inference. (You would need to use PV-DM, 'dm=1', or add skip-gram word-training to PV-DBOW, `dm=0, dbow_words=1`, in order for such reused vectors to have any relevance to your training.)

Why do you think you want/need to use pre-trained vectors? (Especially, a set of 3 million word-vectors, from another kind of data, when a later step suggests you only care about a vocabulary of 20,000 words?)

If for some reason you feel sure you want to initialize `Doc2Vec` with wrod-vectors from elsewhere, and use a training mode where that would have some effect, you can look into the `intersect_word2vec_format()` method that gensim `Doc2Vec` inherits from `Word2Vec`.

That method specifically needs to be called *after* `build_vocab()` has already learned the corpus-specific vocabulary, and it only brings in the words from the outside source that are locally relevant. It's at best an advanced, experimental feature – see its source code, doc-comments, and discussion on the gensim list to understand its side-effects and limitations.